# how to use custom filter within inclusion tag - django

Tags: django, filter, templatetags

I want to use a custom filter inside an inclusion tag in django 1.10, but whenever I try I get an error Invalid filter:'my_filter'  The filter allows me to access a dictionary by a key and returns a value. The filter and inclusion tag work fine by themselves. Can anybody help?

Comment: We’ll need to see your code to get at why this isn’t working for you. The code for your filter as well as your template should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you can’t access your filter, there are usually two primary culprits.

1. You haven’t registered your filter **or**

   ```
   # make sure that your filter is registered
   from django import template

   register = template.Library()

   @register.filter
   def lookup_by_key(value, arg):
       return value[arg]
   ```
2. You forgot to load your filter in your template.

   ```
   # e.g., Your custom filter is in app_name/templatetags/my_filters.py
   {% load my_filters %}
   {{ my_value | lookup_by_key:"6" }}
   ```

If you are using jinja2 templates, you will have to make your custom filter available in your Jinja2 environment initialization.  If you still are having problems, you can [reference the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters).

Comment: You were exactly right--I had to load the filter in the template, whereas I thought I only had to load it on the page that included the template. Thanks!